# How to apply Entity_Filter as OR in Dynamics NAV WebService

Tags: web-services, soap, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav-2009

I am consuming a Dynamics NAV 2009 WebService (SOAPish). Specific I am talking about the ReadMultiple method [MSDNA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff477110.aspx)

The **filterArray** takes an array of **Entity_Filter** objects. Each **Entity_Filter** has a **Field** and **Criteria** property.

Now I want to know, how I can apply the filters as OR not and.

For Example I am passing two filters:

```
Entity_Filter { Field: "Name", Criteria: "*banana*" }
Entity Filter { Field: "Color", Criteria: "yellow"}
```

If I send this to the ReadMultiple I get all entries that have "banana" as part of the name **AND** the color yellow. What do I have to do, to get all Entries that have "banana" as part of the name **OR** the color yellow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to apply an 'OR' filter on a record. ReadMultiple method applies filters the same way C/AL methods SETFILTER or SETRANGE do. It has to be done in two separate requests.

On the second thought, you can do it in a single request, but with an OData service using Linq:

```
NAV nav = new NAV(new Uri("http://ServerName:Port/DynamicsNAV71/OData/Company('Your Company Name')"));
nav.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
var items = from i in nav.ItemsList where i.Name.Equals("Banana") || i.Color.Equals("Yellow") select i;
```

Where 'ItemsList' is an OData web service of type 'Page'

Comment: Is OData available for NAV2009 (not R2) ?

Comment: I did a little research, but it seems OData was introduced for NAV2013, so I guess this won't work for NAV2009 (not R2) :/ too bad.

Comment: No, there are no OData services in 2009. Seems, the data can be retrieved only in 2 requests.